# Creating html input fields out of SQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, html

I'm extracting data from a database with a SELECT statement.
I would like to put this data into something, which you can write in (and later put a button save, which uses a SQL statement to rewrite the rows data).

**The current code is:**
index.php with login logic

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <form action="logik.php" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" />
        DB-Name:  <input type="text" name="dbname" value="unternehmendb" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**After the login the SQL logic:**
logik.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grafik.css">
    <title>unternehmendb</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Mitarbeiter</h1>
    </body>
</html>

<?php   
    //test2
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pwd'];
    $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];

    // Create connection
    $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "<table>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mitarbeiter";
    $result = $link->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Vorname"]. "</td><td> " . $row["Strasse"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Position"] . "</td><td>" . $row["id"] . " </td></tr> ";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if I understand you correctly you want to edit the value `Mitarbeiter` from your database request. So what exactly is the problem? For example you could write the data to a form (like the login form), send then back to the server and change the data it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're on track  but instead of echoing result in **td only**, you can add **text input** fields making the values for the **name attribute** an **array** since you're getting **multiple rows**.

Everything within this

> if($result->num_rows > 0)

block should be changed to:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
   {
    //output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
       echo "<tr>
                <td><input type='text' name='Name[]' value='".$row['Name']."' />  
               </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='Vorname[]' 
                    value='".$row['Vorname']."' /> </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='Strasse[]' 
                    value='".$row['Strasse']."' /> </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='Position[]' value='".   
                    $row['Position']."' /> </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='id[]' value='".$row['id']."' /> 
                    </td>
            </tr> ";

      } //while()
  ?>
   <tr> <td colspan="5"><center> <input type="submit" value="Save Data" /> 
       </center></td></tr>
  <?php
   }// if result rows > 0
?>
```

> Notice that after the loop, we created an additional row to house the
>   submit button.

Assuming there are no records, you could surround your statement in the else with   since it will be printed within the  tag as in:

```
echo "<tr> <td colspan='5'> No results Found </td> </tr>";
```

Hope this helps.